# ListView alignment - how to?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

In a single row, I'd like to align some of the text to the left, and some to the right. For example:

```
|row1-leftmost       row1-rightmost|
|row2-leftmost       row2-rightmost|
|row3-leftmost       row3-rightmost|
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use weight and gravity, weight force textview to take the max of width available but you need to set the width to 0dp, the gravity just place the text in the available space exemple :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="first text"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:gravity="end"
        android:text="second text"/>
</LinearLayout>
```